# How do I rip an audio CD to a single file?

Tags: audio, ubuntu-10.04, ripping

Many programs rip audio as one file per track. I'm looking for a program or method that can rip the whole audio CD to a single file.  Which program or method can do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: One audio file (WAV), one compressed audio file (OGG, FLAC, ...MP3), or one data file (ISO)? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least a command-line application `abcde`, found in the universe, can handle ripping the whole CD into one file.

After installing, the basic usage would be (in Terminal):

```
abcde -1 -a default,cue -o wav
```

The command should create a full-length file with a cue file. Instead of `wav`, you can use `ogg, mp3, flac, spx, mpc, m4a` if you have the codecs.

Answer (score 4):

KDE has this functionality built into the desktop! 
You simply open the audio cd folder and you get:

1. all tracks listed as ogg and mp3 files, each with their own file name.
2. An ogg and mp3 file, named "all" (or similar name) which represents ALL tracks in one file.
3. You also get other codecs listed depending on what is installed.

Now these are not true ogg/mp3 files [yet]. You simply copy any of these virtual files into another folder and kde then creates true audio files in the target folder. Real simple.

See: [What *really* happens with audio CDs in KDE 4.x?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/what-*really*-happens-with-audio-cds-in-kde-4-x-810717/)

(If you have a Gnome ONLY system (I usually have both available) you might try KDE's K3b program which runs on Gnome, but I am not certain if it has this feature.)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a 17 track album (like Abbey Road).

Stick the CD in you computer, open a command line terminal window and navigate to a directory you want your huge WAV file to end up in. Then issue this command:

```
cdparanoia 1-17 -w Abbey.wav
```

1-17 means Tracks 1 to 17
-w means output to a WAV file
"Abbey.wav" is the name of the WAV file that will be created.

Answer (score 0):

`cdparanoia` is pretty neat to rip an audio CD to `wav` files one file per song.
This is a lossless process, and once you have the `wav` files,
you can slice and dice and do anything you want with them,
for example concatenate into a single file using `sox`, for example:

```
cdparanoia -B
sox *.wav cd.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

**fre:ac** is my preferred program in linux. It is fast (supports parallel processing) and supports ripping to a single file. I usually rip my audio books to one mp3. Just make sure to go to 
1) Options>General Settings>Encoders>"Encode to single file"
2) Options>General Settings>Processing>"Treat the combined tracks like a single track"
3) Options>General Settings>Ripper>Settings (here you can check all boxes under "automation" (Read CD contents on insert, Start ripping automatically, Eject disk after ripping)

Good ripping to you :-)